# find the distance of point $P(0,0,1)$ from the level surface $f(x,y,z)=0$ of $f(x, y, z)=\left(z-x^{2}\right)(z+3 y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, surfaces

given $$f(x, y, z)=\left(z-x^{2}\right)(z+3 y)$$

I am asking to find the distance of point $p=(0,0,1)$ from the level surface $f(x, y, z)= 0$.

The idea of what I am asked is pretty simple but How should I execute that?

Comment: This can be a Lagrange multipliers problem

Comment: what is my constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

Objective function $x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2$, which is the square of
the distance from the position $p$, and constrained to
$(z-x^2)(z+3y)=0$.

So, your auxiliary function is $F=x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2+\lambda(z-x^2)(z+3y)$.
Then the equations
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=0,$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=0,$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}=0,$$
together with $(z-x^2)(z+3y)=0$,
going to give you where the distance to the square distance function:
$$x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2,$$
reaches an extremum.

Comment: but who guarantee me that I have extermum? is it a compact region? can I use weirestress theorem?

Comment: do you have any tip how should I solve this system of equations in the efficient way?

Comment: @shinaradistrict: Do you already do the plot of the surface?

Comment: the surface is a kind of a sphere i think?

Comment: play with https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Contourplot3d+%5Bz%5E2+-+x%5E2+z+%2B+3+y+z+-+3+y+x%5E2++%3D%3D0.001%5D to see what kind of surface it is

Comment: **using mathematica as:**  Solve[L (-2 x - 6 x y) + 2 x == 0 && L (3 z - 3 x^2) + 2 y == 0 && 
  L (2 z + 3 y - x^2) + 2 (z - 1) == 0 && (z - x^2) (z + 3 y) == 0 && 
  Element[x, Reals] && Element[y, Reals] && Element[L, Reals] && 
  Element[L, Reals], {L, x, y, z}] **gives** {{L -> 2/9, x -> 0, y -> -(3/10), z -> 9/10}, {L -> 1, 
  x -> -Sqrt[(2/3)], y -> 0, z -> 2/3}, {L -> 1, x -> Sqrt[2/3], 
  y -> 0, z -> 2/3}, {L -> 10, x -> -(Sqrt[22]/5), y -> -(3/10), 
  z -> 9/10}, {L -> 10, x -> Sqrt[22]/5, y -> -(3/10), z -> 9/10}} **where** L **is** $\lambda$

Comment: here is Wolframalpha https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5BL+%28-2+x+-+6+x+y%29+%2B+2+x+%3D%3D+0+%26%26+L+%283+z+-+3+x%5E2%29+%2B+2+y+%3D%3D+0+%26%26+L+%282+z+%2B+3+y+-+x%5E2%29+%2B+2+%28z+-+1%29+%3D%3D+0+%26%26+%28z+-+x%5E2%29+%28z+%2B+3+y%29+%3D%3D+0%2C+%7BL%2C+x%2C+y%2C+z%7D%5D+